# Customer Loading Animation Keyframe/Background Position

Tags: html, css, animation, keyframe

I'm trying to create a custom loading spinner using keyframes and a spritesheet.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Flignats/aaaaaf6h/

My issue is that the spinner appears to be sliding (background position) and I'd like it to be stationary while spinning.

My CSS:

```
.hi {
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64, ... );

    -webkit-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
         -o-animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
            animation: play 1s steps(23) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1496px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1496px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1496px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1496px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -1496px; }
}
```

Comment: Just use 22 steps.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it that adjustment changed the behavior?

Comment: It's not changing the behavior, actually. Your image is 1564px wide, but you're animating down to -1496px, so you're not using the 23 states, but 22. The "sliding" that you're getting is because each keyframe is offset by a few pixels. You can either use 22 steps, or animate down to -1564px.